# Can a method(FormattableString x) overload be called by default when the argument is an interpolated string?

Tags: c#

I have a logging scenario where two overloads are used, for `string` and for `FormattableString`:

```
class Logger
{
    public static void Log(string s)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("It's a string");
    }
    public static void Log(FormattableString s)
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("It's an interpolated string");
    }
}
```

However, both these calls are directed at the `string` overload:

```
Logger.Log("1 string"); // => "It's a string"
Logger.Log($"{1+1} interpolated string"); // => "It's a string"
```

If I explicitly cast the interpolated string, it works.

```
Logger.Log((FormattableString)$"{1+1} interpolated string"); // => "It's an interpolated string"
```

Is there any way to get the `FormattableString` overload be called for the interpolated string, without having to add casts everywhere?

For a bit of context:

The logger must run **without ever throwing exceptions**.

In case of very high memory pressure, even an interpolated string (or rather, its materialization to a normal string) can throw `OutOfMemoryException`, because under the covers it calls `string.Format()` which uses a `StringBuilder` which does memory allocations:

```
var s = $"this is {1+1} interpolated"; //can throw OOM!
```

Calls looking like this must not throw:

```
Logger.Log($"interpolated {1+1}");
```

...so the materialization of the interpolated string must be **deferred** and handled inside the logger, and any exceptions swallowed.

Comment: Looking at the [spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#interpolated-strings), the chances of being able to do this looks slim. Converting interpolated strings to `FormattedString` requires an extra conversion, so the one with the `string` parameter will always be the better function member. Your best bet is have two methods with different names, like `Log` and `LogFormat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to introduce a different type with an implicit conversion from string, pls use like this:

```
class Logger
    {
        public static void Log(String2 s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("It's a string");
        }
        public static void Log(FormattableString s)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("It's an interpolated string");
        }

    }

    public class String2
    {
        public string Value { get; }

        private String2(string str)
        {
            Value = str;
        }

        public static implicit operator String2(string str)
        {
            return new String2(str);
        }
        public static implicit operator String2(FormattableString formattable)
        {
            return new String2(formattable.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Result,

First case:

[image]

Second case:
[image]

Comment: implicit conversion ops are a way out. But with this implementation you get a compile error (I would think) when you pass a string because the compiler doesn't know if he should convert string to String2 or FormattableString, Or are there precedence rules for this case...

Comment: i think this is best solution 

Comment: I tried this in a fiddle (I was attempting the same solution) but I did not work out that you need the second implicit operator (converting from FormattableString to String2) to avoid an ambiguity error when calling with an interpolated string. But I can't understand why that is necessary. Why does the compiler need the second implicit operator instead of just seeing that it can pass the interpolated string straight to the Logger(FormattedString) overload? When is the second implicit operator ever called?

Comment: The fiddle is here if curious... https://dotnetfiddle.net/dULzB7

Comment: @andrew test it again

Comment: @MansurKurtov - I think you misunderstood my comment. Your solution works. Mine did not because I didn't have the second implicit operator defined (`implicit operator String2(FormattableString formattable)`). BUT I don't understand why the second operator is required - when is it used?

Comment: @andrew second operator introduces FormattableString

Comment: @MansurKurtov - Yes the second operator allows implicit conversion from `FormattableString` to `String2` - but why is that needed? A `FormattableString` argument can go straight to `Log(FormattableString)` - why the need to have a conversion from `FormattableString` to `String2` (apart from avoiding the ambiguous call complication error, which is what I'm curious about). Well it works anyway, so that's nice. I was just curious. :)

Comment: @MansurKurtov Brilliant, marked it as the answer, although it needs a small change to fit my updated question (basically, String2 should have a separate ctor for `FormattableString` and hold to that object as-is rather than call ToString() on it)

Comment: @andrew It's interesting that the second `implicit operator` is needed by the compiler but AFAICT not actually called in practice.

Comment: now you have to first create a string2 and no longer cast to FormattbleString.
But where's the benefit? One conversion/cast replaced by the other... ^^

Comment: @lidqy - no you don't need to create a `String2` manually - you just call `Log` with an interpolated string argument and it calls the `Log(FormattableString)` overload. See Mansur's screenshot above. And calling `Log(string)` causes the `String` argument to be implicitly converted to `String2` and then use the `Log(String2)` overload. I agree with the witchcraft description. I presume the compiler has magic for an interpolated string to determine whether it can treat it as a `FormattableString` object or convert it to a `String` (by inlining `String.Format(...)` and its arguments I guess).

Comment: I just tried it on sharplab and this is what it does: `Logger.Log($"interpolated string {1+1}");` is compiled to: `object[] array = new object[1]; array[0] = 2; Logger.Log(FormattableStringFactory.Create("interpolated string {0}", array));`

Comment: Without the `Log(FormattableString)` overload, `Logger.Log($"interpolated string {1+1}");` is compiled to: `Logger.Log(string.Format("interpolated string {0}", 2));`